# html/css break line at midpoint

Tags: html, css

I want to print a title that will span two lines, with the line broken as near the mid-point as possible.
For example, if the title was, say,

> "A Mid-Summer Night's Dream"

I don't want it to break as

> "A Mid-Summer Night's"
>   "Dream"

but more like

> "A Mid-Summer"
>   "Night's Dream"

If the title is long enough to require three lines, I want the lengths of all three to be as close to the same as possible. Etc.

Any way to do this with CSS? Please don't ask me what I've tried so far because I've got no ideas at all. :-(

*Addendum*

Oh, I see from several comments and answers that my question was incomplete. I don't want to embed a br or whatever because, (a) the text is coming from a database, and I don't want to require the user to enter tags, and (b) this is a responsive design, so on a desktop the text should fit on two lines but on a cell phone it might require three, and I don't want arbitrary additional line breaks. For the moment I am requiring hard-coded br's because I don't have another idea, and I have a media query that sets these br's to display:none for cell phones because wrapping wherever it wants on small screens is giving me better results.

Comment: Couldnt you just use a <br/ > tag where you want the title to separate onto a new line? Or am I miss understanding the question?

Comment: @Whirlwind990 the sentences will change , it is just an example i guess.

Comment: You will need javascript to achieve that  , depending on the length of the title.

Comment: @SoorajChandran so how to put an even break in a dynamic sentence? I don't think theres a way to do that via CSS. Maybe possible in Javascript though like you said

Comment: @Whirlwind990 yes javascript is required. As far as i know can't do it in pure css

Comment: @SoorajChandran Yes, it occurred to me after I wrote this that I could write some JS that would find the mid-point of the line and then search for the nearest space on either side and replace the space with a br. I might do that.

Answer (score 2):

use `white-space:nowrap`

Ok if the content is something look like the below

`<div>A Mid-Summer Night's Dream</div>`

Then use the following

`<div>A Mid-Summer <span style="white-space:nowrap;">Night's Dream</span></div>`

put the contents inside the span which you don't want to break.
Let me know if it is worked

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, **justify** is what you are looking for

CSS property : `text-align: justify;`

Additionally, you may also want to use `text-justify: inter-word;`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp

EDIT:
Just checked that this property is only supported in IE

Comment: Anyway this is not what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `white-space: pre-line;` to make elements act like `<pre>`, which preserves newlines.  Example:

```
<style>
 p {
  white-space: pre-line;
 }
</style>
<p>A Mid-Summer 
Night's Dream</p>
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/o3825ec4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This may be (part of) the solution: Add `&nbsp;` instead of a real space between words, so those words stick together when the line breaks.

```
A&nbsp;Mid-Summer Night's&nbsp;Dream
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ca7vhz83/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `ch` unit ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Values_and_Units#distance_units)), which isn't perfect, but gets the thing done quite nicely:

This markup:

```
<style>
h1 {
    width: 20ch;
}
</style>


<h1>"A Mid-Summer Night's  Night's  Night's  Night's  Dream"</h1>
<h1>"A Mid-Summer Night's  Dream"</h1>
```

Will result in this output:

```
"A Mid-Summer 
Night's Night's Night's 
Night's Dream"

"A Mid-Summer
Night's Dream"
```